# Is it possible to install Magento 2 in my Synology?

Tags: magento, magento2, nas, synology

I looked at the package center in the synology OS but only the Magento version is available at the package center. I've searched for answers online but can't seem to find the right one.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install packages is to browse Package Center, which displays a list of approved packages compatible with your Synology NAS model.

Some third-party developers make it simple to check for available applications by creating an .spk repository.

When you want to install a specific version of an application, or when Internet access is not available for automatic download of application files, you can install applications on Synology NAS using .spk files saved on a local computer. Package .spk files are available at Synology's Download Center

https://www.synology.com/en-us/support/download